# Do default parameter values always trump implicits in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit, default-parameters

```
def foo(implicit i: Int = 1) = i
def bar(implicit j: Int) = foo()

bar(4)
```

This piece of code evaluates to `1`. So the default value has priority over the implicit `j`, which is instantiated to `4`. Therefore, it seems that, at least in this example, the default parameter value trumps `implicit`, making the definition of `foo` equivalent to `def foo(i: Int = 1) = i`.

Do default parameter values always trump implicits? If yes, why is this code legal (given that it is confusing)? If not, what is a counter-example?

Is there a way to get the other behavior, i.e. that a piece of code similar to the above (with a default value for `i`) would evaluate to `4`, without having to pass the argument explicitly?

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate the property you think it does. Change `foo()` to `foo` and you'll get the implicit result. Take out the default `= 1` and `foo()` won't compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`implicit` is applied to the entire parameter list, not just a single parameter (e.g., you can have `foo(implicit i: Int, j: Int)`, and both parameters are implicit, but, if you wanted only one of them to be, you'd have to split them in two lists: `def foo(i: Int)(implicit j: Int)`.

So, to pass implicit parameters to the function, you have to omit the entire list: `foo`, not `foo()`.

When you have `def foo(implicit i: Int)`, `foo()` does not even compile, because you are trying to send an empty parameter to list. `foo` does (as long as an implicit int is in scope), because the list is passed implicitly.

With `def foo(implicit i: Int = 1)`, both uses compile, but mean different things. `foo()` means "call `foo` with default values for all parameters", `foo` means "call `foo`, passing the implicit parameter list".

So, with `bar(implicit j: Int) = foo` it will evaluate to the value of `j`, while `bar(implicit j: Int) = foo()` evaluates to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Scala compiler gets confused between `implicit` and default value. `foo()` makes the compiler to ignore `implicit`. so just `foo` does the trick here

```
def foo(implicit i: Int = 1) = i
def bar(implicit j: Int) = foo

println(bar(5))
```

> Result : 5